# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace

Tags: spring, namespaces, xsd

I am running into following problem. I am trying to use Maven or Ivy plugin for eclipse to generate deps from pom.xml file and run a GWT webapp. I have already checked a 100 times that spring-tx is in the dependency. I am using all 3.1.3 versions of spring. And the jar is on the classpath. I checked the maven dependencies library list manually (pom.xml* for Ivy). 
I also checked that META-INF/* files are in place in the jar and not corrupted.

I am not using maven to build/run anything, but eclipse debug target to run the GWT webapp.

I see a lot of threads on internet but none solves my problem. Related: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASSEMBLY-360?

Can someone point me to any possible root cause for this problem?

> Offending resource: ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
>   Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for
>   XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx]
>       Offending resource: class path resource [application-context/hibernate.xml]
>       :
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
>   Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for
>   XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx]
>       Offending resource: class path resource [application-context/hibernate.xml]
>
> ```
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
> ```

Here is my maven pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>UserInterface</groupId>
    <artifactId>UserInterface</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.2-pre8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
                    <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

hibernate.xml namespace declarations

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">
```

Here is a trace of startup before exception is thrown

```
0    [main] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
48   [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment  - Initializing new StandardServletEnvironment
49   [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment  - Adding [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
49   [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment  - Adding [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
53   [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment  - Adding [jndiProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
54   [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment  - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
54   [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment  - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
54   [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment  - Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [servletConfigInitParams,servletContextInitParams,jndiProperties,systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
54   [main] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext  - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun Jan 13 12:15:43 PST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
57   [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment  - Replacing [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with [servletContextInitParams]
[WARN] Server class 'org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
   [WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/home/parth/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-asm/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-asm-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar' to the web app classpath for this session
   For additional info see: file:/home/parth/apps/gwt-2.4.0/doc/helpInfo/webAppClassPath.html
89   [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment  - Initializing new StandardEnvironment
89   [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment  - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
89   [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment  - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
89   [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment  - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
90   [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment  - Initializing new StandardEnvironment
90   [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment  - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
90   [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment  - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
90   [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment  - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
96   [main] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader  - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
98   [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader  - Using JAXP provider [com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl]
119  [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver  - Loading schema mappings from [META-INF/spring.schemas]
120  [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver  - Loaded schema mappings: {http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.1.xsd}
121  [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver  - Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
156  [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader  - Loading bean definitions
165  [main] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader  - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [application-context/properties.xml]
[WARN] Server resource 'application-context/properties.xml' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
   [WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/home/parth/Workspaces/urbanalta/UserInterface/bin/' to the web app classpath for this session
   For additional info see: file:/home/parth/apps/gwt-2.4.0/doc/helpInfo/webAppClassPath.html
167  [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader  - Using JAXP provider [com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl]
168  [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver  - Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
190  [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader  - Loading bean definitions
209  [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate  - Neither XML 'id' nor 'name' specified - using generated bean name [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0]
212  [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader  - Loaded 2 bean definitions from location pattern [classpath:application-context/properties.xml]
212  [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader  - Imported 2 bean definitions from URL location [classpath:application-context/properties.xml]
212  [main] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader  - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [application-context/datasource.xml]
214  [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader  - Using JAXP provider [com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl]
215  [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver  - Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
234  [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader  - Loading bean definitions
235  [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader  - Loaded 1 bean definitions from location pattern [classpath:application-context/datasource.xml]
235  [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader  - Imported 1 bean definitions from URL location [classpath:application-context/datasource.xml]
235  [main] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader  - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [application-context/hibernate.xml]
236  [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader  - Using JAXP provider [com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl]
238  [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver  - Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
564  [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver  - Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.1.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.1.xsd
572  [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader  - Loading bean definitions
574  [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver  - Loaded NamespaceHandler mappings: {http://www.springframework.org/schema/p=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.SimplePropertyNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/c=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.SimpleConstructorNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang=org.springframework.scripting.config.LangNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee=org.springframework.ejb.config.JeeNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.UtilNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache=org.springframework.cache.config.CacheNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task=org.springframework.scheduling.config.TaskNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context=org.springframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler}
576  [main] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:application-context/hibernate.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx]
Offending resource: class path resource [application-context/hibernate.xml]
```

Comment: Please show us the top of your `application-context/hibernate.xml` file where `tx` namespace is declared.

Comment: I edited the original post and appended it ... let me know if you want to see the whole file.

Comment: Can you post your full spring configuration for that file? It seems it's not resolving an entity as it should. Also update the log to use the `TRACE` level for `org.springframework.beans.factory.xml`. You can also see from the last log entry that it hasn't found the namespace handler for the transaction namespace so the issue should come from there.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: I had the same error. The fix was that the tx jar was not getting reflected in External Dependencies in maven, so I did following. pom.xml-> maven-> reload project. Then , I just clean compiled, and the problem is fixed.